# How do I write an IF ELSE to check string contents of an array?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, arrays, nsstring

I'm trying to write an IF ELSE statement to enable shipping, If user doesn't add an address the array contents remain as "-" & "-" for the two items in the array.  I want to check to see if those are in the array, if they are then I want to enableshipping.

Here is the code for getting the array:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/arraySaveFile", documentsDirectory];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];
```

How do I write this first line to look for the "-" & "-"?

```
if ([fullFileName isEqualToString:@"-","-"]) 
{
[nnNEP EnableShipping];
}
else {
    [nnNEP DisableShipping];
}
```

Thanks,

michael

Comment: Something isn't lining up there with your code.  You have a pathname in `fullFileName`, but you want to look in the array, right?

Comment: Michael Robinson: `@"-","-"` is a comma expression. The comma operator comes from C, and evaluates both sides, with the result of the evaluation being that of the right side. Thus, this expression works out to `"-"`, which is a C string—which you *do not* want to pass to `isEqualToString:`. Another, more minor, problem: You should not use `stringWithFormat:` to construct paths. NSString and NSURL have dedicated path-construction methods; use those to more explicitly state your intent and in some cases get better results.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll look into the these good points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to check the contents of the first two items of the array and not fullFileName.

For example:

```
if ([[array objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"-"] 
      && [[array objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"-"])
{
    [nnNEP EnableShipping];
}
else
{
    [nnNEP DisableShipping];
}
```